# Material Carousel dependency error when installing

Tags: angular, angular-material, carousel, node-modules

I would like to use [@ngbmodule/material-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngbmodule/material-carousel/v/0.7.2) however I am receiving the following dependency errors

```
Found: @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/material@"^10.0.1" from @ngbmodule/material-carousel@0.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngbmodule/material-carousel
npm ERR!   @ngbmodule/material-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/dtech/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

I've forced the installation which passed the dependency issue and caused it work fine locally. However when I deploy to Vercel. The deployment fails there again

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @ngbmodule/material-carousel@0.7.2
npm ERR! Found: @angular/material@13.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"^13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/material@"^10.0.1" from @ngbmodule/material-carousel@0.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngbmodule/material-carousel
npm ERR!   @ngbmodule/material-carousel@"^0.7.2" from the root project
```

Answer (score -1):

try to delete the node_modules
and install the package again  :

```
npm install --save @ngbmodule/material-carousel
```

then use `npm i` to install all packages

if not works try to  use the popular version: 0.7.2

```
npm install --save @ngbmodule/material-carousel@0.7.2
```

Comment: Neither have worked